# Call explorer context menu in listview

Tags: vb.net, windows-explorer, contextmenustrip

Below image is a screenshot of beyond compare which calls windows explorer context menu of a file/folder when right-click and select **Explorer** menu.

[Call-Explorer-Context-Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMmRB.png)

Please help to make it on vb.net, or please share a link for a tutorial. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thats the shell or Explorer menuing system.  To implement one on a ListView you probably need to add your own (which will probably be easier than all the PInvokes to use Explorer's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the shell menu of a file/folder you must ask the containing folders `IShellFolder` for a `IContextMenu` instance. Checkout this blog series called [How to host an IContextMenu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823) for all the details.

There is a .NET version of it [here](http://andrewvos.com/2007/07/04/shell-context-menu).